# Contact form 7 not show success message?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have copied code about contact form 7 wordpress, currently the data has been successfully sent to the database external, but the messages success are almost not displayed as well as I have moved to the thank you page. Thank you

```
function wpcf7_send_to_external ( $cf7 ) {

//external db details
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';
$database = 'database';
$host = 'myip';


//create new wpdb instance
$mydb = new wpdb($username, $password, $database, $host);


        $cf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();


        $field1 = $data["name"];
        $field2 = $data["semail"];
        $field3 = $data["phone"];
        $field4 = $data["nhu"];


        //insert into external db
        $mydb->insert( 

            'customer',

            array( 
                'name' => $field1, 
                'email' => $field2,
                'phone' => $field3,
                'content' => $field4
            ),

            array( 
                '%s','%s','%s','%s'
            ) 
        );
```

}

add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_send_to_external");

Comment: If you want to store the Fields in the Contact Form, then there are plugins available. Eg: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/ It would do the job for you in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's called from a JavaScript file you could just do a console.log there.

```
console.log("Success message!");
```

If you need data from the PHP file you can send it back with an echo. (Which can be accessed as the response to the HTTP request.

```
echo "some data: $variable";
```

Comment: Thanks, i add some code, if ($submission) , if ( empty ($posted_data)) return ;